# Continuous Images of Arc Connected spaces

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

**Arc Connected:** $X$ is arc connected if for any $x,y\in X$, $\exists$ homeomorphism $f:I\to X$ such that $f(0) = x, f(1) = y.$

If $g:X\to Y$ is a continuous surjective function and $X$ is arc connected, is $Y$ arc connected too?

I don't think so, but haven't been able to find a proof/counterexample in a book. Also, Wikipedia says that $Y$ should be arc connected.

**My Reasoning:** As in path-connected, the function $g \circ f$ is a continuous map from $I$ to $Y$, but this need not be a homeomorphism.

Comment: Do you mean $f$ to be a *homeomorphism* on $I\to X$? Usually it's just a path with $I$ homemomorphic to $f(I)$ not $X$.

Comment: Also you should assume that "for $x\neq y$".

Comment: @Chrystomath: I can't speak for the OP, but not everyone limits 'homeomorphism $f:I\to X$' to the case in which $f$ is a surjection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. An image of arc connected (in your definition $f$ should be a homeomorphism onto image, not just homeomorphism) space does not have to be arc connected.

Consider $[0,1]$ with the Euclidean topology. Now put $x\sim y$ iff $x=y=1$ or $x,y\in [0,1)$. So we collapse $[0,1)$ to a point. Finally take the quotient map $q:[0,1]\to[0,1]/\sim$. Note that the quotient is not arc connected.

The same works with any arc connected space and a relationship that produces at most countable (greater than $1$) number of equivalence classes.